# Show the percentage of process completion in a C++ program

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, io, percentage

I am making a set of C++ library as a part of my Data Structures assignment, which includes custom implementation of vector, sorting algorithms, stacks, etc. I am supposed to work on the running time of sorting algorithms, bubble sort, selection sort, quick sort, etc., which are part of my library.

Now the data set given to test the algorithms in of the order of 10^6. I ran bubble sort on a data of 2*10^6 elements, and it took about 138 minutes for the program to run, and in all this time, I did not know if my sorting algorithm is working correctly or not, or is it even working or not. I would want to add another feature to the sorting functions, i.e they could display the percentage of sorting done, and I think this is possible, since algorithms like bubble sort are deterministic.

I need a message like something to appear as soon as I start the process:

> Bubble sort under progress. Done: 17%

This percentage is to be determined by the algorithm. Consider the example of bubble sort with 10000 elements. If you look at the bubble sort algorithm(refer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), it has 2 loops, and after each iteration of the main loop, one element is fixed to its correct position in the sorted array. So after like 1 iteration, the percentage should increase by 0.01%.

Though this percentage calculation has a problem that in this case, the time for the percentage to increase keeps on decreasing, but something like this would do.

Also, this number should increase as and when required, on the same place. But I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: The problem is that most computers are not just running your program. They have other things in hand that effects performance so they will have to make a guess

Comment: Time the first x% and extrapolate.

Comment: How  are you going to calculate that percentage? Once you've determined that, the display is simple. The calculation, however, is anything but simple. Given 1000 items, how does your sort algorithm know it's reached 17% of the sort, when by nature a bubble sort is highly repetitive?

Comment: @EdHeal No. If you observe the algorithm of bubble sort, after every main iteration, 1 element is correctly placed to it's position, either in the start or at the end. Consider the loop has 100 elements, so after every main loop, the progress increases by 1%. The computer has nothing to do with it anyways.

Comment: @SahilArora: *so after every main loop, the progress increases by 1%* false. Bubble sort gets faster at every iteration. The first iteration takes ~N, the second ~N-1, the third ~N-2 and so on.

Comment: But you have a computer that is running multiple processes at the same time.

Comment: @JonathanPotter how?

Comment: @KenWhite Question details edited, added how percentage can be calculated.

Comment: `1- num_sorted/num_to_sort`

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, I agree. But it could also show up something like, no. of elements sorted = 100/1000. I have edited the description, have a look.

Comment: @user4581301 I get that, but how do I make the function return the percentage, or print, that too on the same spot.

Comment: @SahilArora: well, then just print it when you are inside the loop ([example](http://pastebin.com/THXrPqxg)), what's so difficult about it?

Comment: @MatteoItalia This will print a new on each line. I need to print it at the same place. Like:
1%, then after some time this 1 changes to 2, 2%. I do not want something like:
1%
2%
3%
4%
...

This is the problem.

Comment: Google `ncurses` library

Comment: Use the carriage return character (`\r`) to reposition at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Brute force: `std::cout` a '\b' for every character in the previous percentage, then `std::cout << currentPercent;`

Comment: Dang it @MatteoItalia Why do it the easy way?

Comment: @EdHeal sorry I did not mention, without any external library support

Comment: @MatteoItalia yeah this may work.

Comment: Don't forget to flush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback function of a generic type to your bubblesort function and call the function at reasonable intervals.

This will impact performance, but this shouldn't be a concern when you're using bubblesort anyway.

First we'll need some includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
```

And then the bubblesort function, which I essentially took from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void bubblesort(std::vector<T> &v, Func callback) {
    size_t const len = v.size();
    size_t n = v.size();
    while(n > 0) {
        size_t newn = 0;
        for(size_t i = 1; i <= n-1; ++i) {
            if (v[i - 1] > v[i]) {
                std::swap(v[i-1], v[i]);
                newn = i;
            }
        }
        n = newn;
        callback(100-static_cast<int>(n*100/len));
    }
}
```

We will call the given callback function (or use operator() on an object) whenever it's done sorting in one element.

The parameter we pass is an integer percentage of how far we've come. Note that due to integer arithmetic you cannot change the order of operations with n*100/v.size() or else it would always result in 0, since n will always be smaller than v.size();

```
using namespace std::chrono; //to avoid the horrible line becoming even longer

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec; 

    /* fill vector with some data */
    std::mt19937 generator(static_cast<unsigned long>(duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count())); //oh god
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(static_cast<int>(generator()));
    }
```

For initialization we get create a random number generator and seed it with the current time. Then we put some elements in the vector.

```
    char const *prefix = "Bubble sort under progress. Done: ";
    int lastp = -1;
    bubblesort(vec, [&lastp,prefix](int p){
        //if progress has changed, update it
        if(p != lastp) {
            lastp = p;
            std::cout << "\r" << prefix << p << "%" << std::flush;
            /*std::flush is needed when we don't start a new line
              '\r' puts the cursor to the start of the line */
        }
    });

    std::cout << "\r" << prefix << "100%" << std::endl;
    //make sure we always end on 100% and end the line
}
```

Now the core part: we pass a C++ lambda function to our bubblesort function as a callback. Our bubblesort function will then call this lambda with the percentage value and write it to the screen.

And voilà, we got ourselves some neat output:

https://youtu.be/iFGN8Wy9T3o

## Closing notes:

You can of course integrate the lamda function into the sort function itself, however I would not recommend this as you lose a lot of flexibility. But it's a design choice that's up to you - if you don't need the flexibility, just hardcode it.

The percentage is not very accurate, in fact knowing you're at 20% (and how long it took to get there) does not tell you much at all about the time it will take to get to 100% as it could very well be, that the last 20% of the vector were sorted (and thus were quick to sort with bubblesort - O(n)), but the remaining 80% are random, and take O(n^2) to sort.
In fact all it tells you is that you're making progress, but that's all you wanted in the first place so I guess that's okay.

If you want a more accurate percentage adjust your program like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
/* ... */
callback(10000-static_cast<int>(n*10000/len));
/* ... */
std::cout.fill('0'); //to fill leading zero of p%100
std::cout << "\r" << prefix << p/100 << "." << std::setw(2) << p%100 << "%" << std::flush;
```

If you decide to use floating point values instead remember to clear remnant characters from previous outputs - "\r" only resets the cursor position, but does not clear the line.

Use `std::cout.precision(3);` for a fixed precision or write some spaces after your message to clear previous runs.

Comment: Whoa man! This is gold. I don't know why I did not accept this answer back then. Thanks a lot!
Also, why don't you make the video public?

Answer (score 1):

For the special case of bubblesort, you can take the number of elements you have, then divide that by 100. If you have 552 elements, then you will get 5. (integers make sense to work with). Then, have a counter in your loop. If the counter is a multiple of 5, (you've so far sorted 5 elements) then you can increase the percentage by 1 and print it. As far as printing it so that the percentage appears on the spot instead of printing below, you can print backspaces! Either that or try using the ncurses library, though that might be overkill. Finally, a different way to do this might be to use a linux style progress bar that is 50 characters long or something similar.

Comment: I thought of the progress bar only after posting the question! I'll try anyway. And cannot use ncurses library.